# How to obtain the driver name in kernel space given a vendor and device ID?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

Given a vendor ID and device ID , I want to obtain the driver name of the device in kernel space.
In fact, I get the vendor and device ID for a device using for_each_pci_dev() function, but I need the driver's name of each device. How can match the vendor and device ID to driver name?
Please help me...
Thanks 
Narges

Comment: Why do you need this in kernel space? User can easily get the information by invoking `lspci -k`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i need do this as a kernel module. in fact i want get Ethernet card driver during boot and use request_module() to load it.I know that udev load this module after kernel uevent, but i deeply need to load this module manually. thanks

Comment: Compile it in the kernel. Problem solved.